# Meteor Package - Iron:router - How to prevent my package routes to execute the hooks of the apps that use it?

Tags: meteor, package, iron-router

I am creating a meteor package using iron:router, it works great.
The routes logic of this package is very specific.

But as soon as I add this package in a Meteor app **that is also using iron:router**, the hooks defined by the Meteor app (onBeforeAction, onAfterAction, ...) are called for the routes created by the package.
I'd like to prevent my package routes to execute the hooks of the app.

Is there a simple piece of code I could use to isolate the routes of my package from the "external" hooks? Maybe I could create a specific RouteController?

The last option for me is to implement a router from scratch...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that solved my issue is the following:

```
let MyRouter = new Iron.Router;
MyRouter.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.json());
MyRouter.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

The solution is to declare a new isolated router. The 2 lines under the router declaration enable to retrieve the data of POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create isolated controller:

```js
var MyPackageController = RouteController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function () { ... },
  onAfterAction: function () { ... }
  /* other options */
});

Router.map(function () {
   this.route('packageRoute', {
      controller: MyPackageController
      /* other options */
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried your piece of code, but the hooks configured in the app are still called. I imagine that if I extend the RouteController with some hooks defined by the app, it will concatenate (and not replace) them with the package hooks. That is what I experience right now. Maybe I could declare a dedicated RouteController for my package?

Comment: You're facing the rule's inherence, and you can't do anything about it, as it is strict: Router --> RouteController --> Route . So, whenever you add rules to Router all RouteControllers (including your package) will inherit it

Comment: I am trying to... but I am not really sure how to do that properly. My intents didn't work. Maybe FlowRouter is more flexible on this (I have never used this package).

Comment: Use underscore's `var isolatedRouter = _.clone(Router);` Actually it is a problem of both FR and IR - you can not call `new`, as they comes as singletons.

Comment: Thanks, but the clone function from underscore does not work. The isolatedRouter will also call the hooks associated to the Router. :/ Another solution would be to prevent the hooks to be called for specific routes, I don't think there is such an option, maybe you have an idea about that?

Comment: The definition of the clone function is "Create a shallow-copied clone of the provided plain object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated." That is because of the nested references that the hooks are called.

Comment: The only way I see here is to avoid shared hooks, like `onBeforeAction` and `onAfterAction`. And put all logic into `action` hook. Then `onAfterAction` logic can be placed into `Template.myTemplate.onRendered` callback. Can you post a link to your package? Maybe another idea comes after I see its code